# How to make list of array objects with key value pair in php or laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
number=["11","22","32","42","52"]
amount=["10","10","10","10","10"]
list=[
    {"number":"11", "amount":"10"},
    {"number":"22", "amount":"10"},
    {"number":"32", "amount":"10"},
    {"number":"42", "amount":"10"},
    {"number":"52", "amount":"10"}
]
```

I have two different array (number and amount), both arrays will have fixed length. I need to make another array list object with key value pair.

Code...

```
$i=0; 
$new_arr=array(); 
foreach($number as $num) { 
    foreach($amount as $amt) { 
        $new_amt[$i]; 
        $data=array( 'number'=>$num, 'amount'=>$new_amt ); 
        array_push($new_arr, $data); 
    } 
} 

print_r($new_arr);
```

---

I tried in this way

```
$new_arr = [];
foreach ($number as $num) {
    foreach ($amount as $amt) {
        $data = [
            'number' => $num,
            'amount' => $amt,
        ];
    }
    array_push($new_arr, $data);
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the issue then?

Comment: Also why nested foreach?

Comment: you need an array of objects, or are you just calling an array an "array list object"?

Answer (score 1):

in PHP you can easly convert array to object just casting it with `(Object)`, so you could solve your problem with something like:

```php
$list=array(); 
for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($number); $i++) { 
   array_push($list, (Object)["number" => $number[$i], "amount" => $amount[$i]]);
}
```